# fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals

Tags: visual-c++

how can i solve this ,when i compile my source im got this error

```
Neuz.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved 

EditString.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "public: void __thiscall CEditString::ParsingString(char const *,unsigned long,unsigned long,unsigned short,class ATL::CStringT<char,class StrTraitMFC<char,class ATL::ChTraitsCRT<char> > > &,class CDWordArray &,class CByteArray &,class CWordArray &,unsigned long)" (?ParsingString@CEditString@@QAEXPBDKKGAAV?$CStringT@DV?$StrTraitMFC@DV?$ChTraitsCRT@D@ATL@@@@@ATL@@AAVCDWordArray@@AAVCByteArray@@AAVCWordArray@@K@Z) referenced in function "public: void __thiscall CEditString::AddParsingString(char const *,unsigned long,unsigned long,unsigned short,unsigned long)" (?AddParsingString@CEditString@@QAEXPBDKKGK@Z)
```

Comment: Probably you have to add the file into your workspace.

Comment: Can you provide context? What development environment are you using?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Look at other questions and the help pages to learn asking questions.

Answer (score 2):

If the class CEditString is implemented in one of your source files then add the source file to your project.

If the class CEditString is implemented in a library (.LIB) then add the library to your project.
If the class CEditString is implemented in a DLL then add the import library to your project.
In the latter two cases verify that you have included the correct and unchanged header files matching the exported symbols. You can use `dumpbin` to see the exported symbols of the LIB and the DLL.